# OK to use these two parameters each independently, but fail to have both

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I use msvc 2017 community. When I test the following code:

```
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void UseArray(
    T (&arr)[10]) {
    arr[0] = 0;
}

template<class T>
void UseFunction(
    function<bool(T, T)> para = [](T x, T y) { return x == y; }) {
    para(1, 2);
}

template<class T>
void UseArrayAndFunction( 
    T (&arr)[10],       // <-- All errors are here
    function<bool(T, T)> para = [](T x, T y) { return x == y; } ) {
    arr[0] = 0;
    para(1, 2);
}

int main() {
    int arr[10];
    UseArray<int>(arr);
    UseFunction<int>();
    UseArrayAndFunction<int>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The first two functions are OK, but the last one has the following errors (all locate in the 18th line):

```
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(18): error C2065: 'arr': undeclared identifier
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(18): error C2275: 'std::function<bool(T,T)>': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(12): note: see declaration of 'std::function<bool(T,T)>'
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'para'
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(18): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\cpptest3\cpptest3\main.cpp(19): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

Could you tell me what causes these errors?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. It works ok with g++ 7.3.0, using `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you tell me what causes these errors?

A MSVC bug causes those errors. Your last function is well-formed C++. You can get around this bug by avoiding the array declarator:

```
template<class T, typename ArrT = T[10]>
void UseArrayAndFunction( 
    ArrT &arr,       
    std::function<bool(T, T)> para = [](T x, T y) { return x == y; } ) {
    arr[0] = 0;
    para(1, 2);
}
```

Which builds fine on MSVC 19.10 (VS 2017). See it [live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/CfBPQR).

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought I could meet a compiler bug.

Comment: @landings - Sadly they are quite common (and at times. downright weird).